# Should I put JWT on JSON as base64 string?

Tags: json, jwt, json-api, json-web-token

I design REST API for my site. I read some info about proper JSON-API. And now draft version is look like:

```
{
"data":
  {
   //data that I will send
  },
"errors":"", 
"meta": 
  {
    "token": // auth info for ever request
      {
        // JWT token here
      }
  }
}
```

But I can't understand should I put JWT token as base64 string like:
`"token" : "base64encodedstring"`

or should I put JWT as nested object in "token"?

Also I have got question. Am I right understand that it's good practice to use once designed JSON-API everywhere? I mean that same JSON (with different `data` section will be used for auth, for data exchange and so on)

Comment: When you create (sign) a token, it's already a `Base64Url`-encoded string, or to be more precise, a string concatenated from two to three `Base64Url`-encoded strings (wether you signed it or not) which looks like this (trimmed) `eyJhbGci[...].eyJzdW[...].TJVA[...]`. When you want to authorize with it, you generally send a Basic-auth request: `Authorization: Bearer <token>`, and your server is responsible for checking the token's authenticity by comparing its signature. So yeah, you should use this encoded string. Second question: short answer — yes makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the JWT is in compact serialization format (3 or 5 parts separated by dots), then it is not necessary to encoded it. 
Otherwise, if it is in flattened or general serialization format (a JSON object), then you will have to encode it.